# Test for how many of a certain value are in a text file (batch)?

Tags: batch-file

I need to look through a text file (quickly) and for every line that contains a specific value (represented as %Val%), and I basically want do this: "set /a Count+=1" so that by the end of it %Count% = number of %Val% in text file. Here's what I have, but it takes waay to long cause it has to got though all couple hundred lines in the file:

```
set Count=0
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%File%") do (
  if "%%a" == "%Val%" set /a Count+=1
)
echo.%Count%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FINDSTR to find lines that exactly match your search, and pipe the results to FIND to count the number of matches. Use a FOR /F loop to capture the result.

```
for /f %%N in ('findstr /xlc:"%val%" "%file%"^|find /c /v ""') do set count=%%N
```

Comment: If I ignore it, and try again it says "FINDSTR: Cannot open"

Comment: Never mind, the error was on my part. I forgot to deffine val. But your code works great!